# System.web.optimization AssetManager increases memory usage

Tags: asp.net, memory-management, asp.net-optimization

I am doing so memory analysis for our project there is excessive usage of memory.

This is what I got when I did a deep analysis.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have recently found that minifing large minified files via `ScriptBundle` can cause excessive memory usage.

In my case changing

**From:**`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/Scripts/").Include(....`

**To:**`bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Bundles/Scripts/").Include(....`

Reduced my memory usage by around 300mb.

Long term this obviously isn't a great solution, and you should probably move to another solution ("Gulp" or "Bower"), but this may be enough to get through the next release or two.

Comment: I had the same memory issue. After changing from "ScriptBundle" to "Bundle" the memory reserved for my ppp dropped by 50%. Here is a interesting article for a alternative: https://mentormate.com/blog/file-bundling-minification-make-better-web-apps