# Debugging Memory Leak on Azure Web App: Memory Analysis Fails

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, azure-web-app-service, .net-4.8

I'm trying to diagnose a memory leak on an Azure Web App.

I use the Diagnose and Solve Problems > Diagnostic Tools > Collect Memory Dump (tool referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030776/how-to-debug-azure-web-app-memory-leaks/36080826#36080826)).

This collects a dmp file and generates an analysis report. I can see the threads and other information in the Crash Hang Analysis, but the DotNetMemoryAnaysis always fails with error

```
Type:  System.OutOfMemoryException

Message:  Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Stack Trace:
DebugDiag.DotNet.NetDbgObj.d__73.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__1.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable.d__25`1.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.GCRootWalker.ShowRoots(NetScriptManager manager, NetDbgObj debugger, NetProgress progress, IEnumerable`1 top40Query) in C:\src\DebugDiag\Development\src\DebugDiag.AnalysisRules\DotNetMemoryAnalysis.cs:line 1875
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.DoDotNetMemoryAnalysis() in C:\src\DebugDiag\Development\src\DebugDiag.AnalysisRules\DotNetMemoryAnalysis.cs:line 222
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.RunAnalysisRule(NetScriptManager manager, NetProgress progress) in C:\src\DebugDiag\Development\src\DebugDiag.AnalysisRules\DotNetMemoryAnalysis.cs:line 182
DebugDiag.DotNet.NetAnalyzer.RunAnalysisRulesInternal(DumpFileType bitness, NetProgress progress, String symbolPath, String imagePath, String reportFileFullPath, Boolean twoTabs, AnalysisModes analysisMode)
```

I tried analyzing the file with the `dotnet-dump` cli tool, but it errors for any analysis action with
`SOS does not support the current target architecture 0x0000014c`.
Opening the dmp in Visual Studio also does not appear to offer any analysis options, just debugging.

Is there a way I can run analysis for the dmp from another machine? Is there a different way I should collect the dump?

### Update

The analysis tool used by azure web apps on windows can be downloaded at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=58210

This did not solve my problem though. I still get an out of memory exception.

I monitored the system memory usage, and it never got close to topping out.

Increased GCRootTimeout in `Program Files\DebugDiag\AnalysisRules\DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.dll.config`.

I also set [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element) in every config file I could find.

Comment: I just want to confirm that you're running S1 or higher SKU on your app service plan? Is your app .NETCORE or .NETFX? Version? If you have the dump file, have you tried using [WinDb](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PGJGD53TN86)? What's the app name? To share privately, send it to _AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com_ ATTN Ryan and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. My app service plan is a P1V2 running a .Net Framework 4.8 Asp.NET MVC 5 site. I hadn't tried WindDbg yet. I've now loaded the dmp in WinDbg, but it wasn't readily apparent how to get the info I need. I'm going to need to research and experiment a bit.

I'll send the specific site details to the email shortly. Thanks again!

Comment: You'll want to start with `.loadby sos clr` to load the [SOS extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension) so you can use the !dumpobj command. This will list out the objects that's in the dmp file by instance count and size. If you run into issues with .loadby, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your dump file @farlee2121. I opened your dump file using [WinDbg](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PGJGD53TN86) and kicked off `!analyze -v`. This will pull available symbols to your local cache.

```
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1D
         https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         SOS_x86_x86_4.8.4180.00.dll
         5E7D1ED77b0000
SYMSRV:  PATH: C:\debug\sym\SOS_x86_x86_4.8.4180.00.dll\5E7D1ED77b0000\SOS_x86_x86_4.8.4180.00.dll
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: C:\debug\sym\SOS_x86_x86_4.8.4180.00.dll\5E7D1ED77b0000\SOS_x86_x86_4.8.4180.00.dll - OK
```

When trying to look at the heap, `!dumpheap -stat`, resulted in...

```
Object <exec cmd="!ListNearObj /d 5cdcf038">5cdcf038</exec> has an invalid method table.
0:000> !ListNearObj /d 5cdcf038
Before:  5cdcf014           36 (0x24)   System.Collections.Hashtable+HashtableEnumerator
After:  couldn't find any object between 0x5cdcf038 and 0x5cdd00cc
Heap local consistency not confirmed.
```

...which could indicate GC was possibly running at the time the dump was being collected. There two options we can do at this point. One is use [mex extension](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53304) and run `!mex.dumpheap2` or use [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview) to analyze the heap.

Mex showed a fair amount of Automapper objects

```
1,014,591 20,291,820 System.Linq.Expressions.FullConditionalExpression
2,873     24,391,820 System.Char[]
1,541,328 24,661,248 System.Linq.Expressions.AssignBinaryExpression
1,680,035 26,880,560 AutoMapper.Mappers.ConvertMapper+<>c__DisplayClass1_1
1,571,447 31,428,940 System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression
1,680,036 33,600,720 System.Lazy<System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression>
1,194,017 33,941,972 System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[]
3,161,253 37,935,036 System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression
9,941     39,286,832 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary+Entry<AutoMapper.TypePair,System.Lazy<System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression>>[]
844,692   39,384,092 System.Reflection.MemberInfo[]
665,549   47,919,528 AutoMapper.PropertyMap
1,680,036 53,761,152 System.Func<System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression>
253,050   58,765,632 System.Int32[]
339,941   61,674,100 System.String
25,206    70,703,012 System.Byte[]
Total 37,374,335 Object(s), Total Size: 1.03 GB, Free Objects 812(352.21 KB)
```

If you use Perfview though to open the dump and Dump GC Heap, we can get a better picture

```
Name                                                                                                                                        Inc %              Inc
 LIB <<System.Core!Linq.Expressions.Expression>>>                                                                                            21.8      214,783,296
+ AutoMapper!AutoMapper.TypeMap                                                                                                              21.8      214,783,296
 + LIB <<mscorlib!Dictionary>>                                                                                                               21.8      214,783,296
 |+ AutoMapper!AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration                                                                                                21.8      214,783,296
 ||+ AutoMapper!AutoMapper.Mapper                                                                                                            21.8      214,783,296
 |||+ Fourstarzz.Accessors!Fourstarzz.Accessors.EntityFramework.DtoMapper                                                                    21.8      214,783,296
 ||||+ Fourstarzz.Accessors!Fourstarzz.Accessors.IntegrationAccessInfoAccessor                                                               21.8      214,783,296
 |||||+ Fourstarzz.Managers!Fourstarzz.Managers.Identity.AccountConnectionManager                                                            10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||+ Fourstarzz.Managers.Adapters!Fourstarzz.Managers.Adapters.Identity.OkanjoRegistrationHandler                                        10.9      108,058,320
 |||||| + Fourstarzz.Managers.Adapters!Fourstarzz.Managers.Adapters.Identity.CompositeIdentityEventHandler                                   10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||  + Fourstarzz.Managers!Fourstarzz.Managers.Identity.UserIdentityManager                                                              10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   + Fourstarzz.Clients.Website!Fourstarzz.Clients.Website.IdentityWrapper                                                            10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |+ LIB <<System!Stack<Object>>>                                                                                                    10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   | + Autofac!Autofac.Core.Disposer                                                                                                  10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  + Autofac!Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope                                                                                   10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  |+ LIB <<mscorlib!Func>>                                                                                                        10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | + Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin!Owin.AppBuilderExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1                                                 10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | |+ LIB <<mscorlib!Func,Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext,Fourstarzz.Shared.FourstarzzIdentity.FourstarzzUserManager>>>              10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | ||+ Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin!Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryProvider                                     10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | || + Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin!Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryOptions                                     10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | ||  + Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin!Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware>                                10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | ||   + Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin!Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware>                               10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | ||    + Microsoft.Owin!Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinMiddlewareTransition                                                 10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | ||     + LIB <<Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb!Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineBlueprint>>   10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | ||      + [static var Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule._blueprint]                                                10.9      108,058,320
 ||||||   |  | ||       + [static vars]                                                                                                      10.9      108,058,320
```

Here are some things to proceed further. First, change your web app from x86 to x64 on the **Application Settings** blade, that will at least give you some more breathing room. Upon restarting your app, collect a memory dump from the **Diagnose and sovle problems** blade to get a baseline. Then configure [AutoHeal](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/09/10/Announcing-the-New-Auto-Healing-Experience-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html) to collect a dump file when memory reaches an upper threshold to get around OOM you're running into. Furthermore, Perfview will allow you compare to dump heaps so you can see which objects are growing in allocation; check Starting an Analysis help in Perfview for more info.

In my personal experience, AutoMapper can cause performance issues if not properly configured. I once was creating a Mapper each time I processed data when it wasn't necessary. It also looks like you adding an Mapper to your AutoFac IoC container and that mapper has reference to an EventHandler. Event handlers can pin objects to the heap, preventing the GC to collect it.

Comment: This is really helpful!  I poked around and I don't explicitly bind AutoMapper via AutoFac anywhere. I try to keep it as an internal detail to the class. I do have a static cache for some of the mappers though. That would cause the it to be pinned too.

Comment: Auto heal is kind tucked away, but it packs a lot of possibilities

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with DebugDiag hitting an out of memory exception, with a slightly different stack trace:

```
Type:  System.OutOfMemoryException

Message:  Array dimensions exceeded supported range.

Stack Trace:
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Resize(Int32 newSize, Boolean forceNewHashCodes)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.GCRootWalker.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0(UInt64 child, Int32 offset)
Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.GCDesc.WalkObject(UInt64 addr, UInt64 size, MemoryReader cache, Action`2 refCallback)
Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.Desktop.DesktopHeapType.EnumerateRefsOfObject(UInt64 objRef, Action`2 action)
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.GCRootWalker.FindRootChains(ClrHeap heap, HashSet`1 typesOfInterest, ClrRootChain rootChain, HashSet`1 allObjects, Action`2 onRootVisit)
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.GCRootWalker.FindRootChains(ClrHeap heap, HashSet`1 typesOfInterest, Action`1 preEnumerate, Action`2 onRootVisit)
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.GCRootWalker.ShowRoots(NetScriptManager manager, NetDbgObj debugger, NetProgress progress, IEnumerable`1 top40Query)
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.DoDotNetMemoryAnalysis()
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.DotNetMemoryAnalysis.RunAnalysisRule(NetScriptManager manager, NetProgress progress)
DebugDiag.DotNet.NetAnalyzer.RunAnalysisRulesInternal(DumpFileType bitness, NetProgress progress, String symbolPath, String imagePath, String reportFileFullPath, Boolean twoTabs, AnalysisModes analysisMode)
```

In this situation it did work to add [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element) into these two config files:

- C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\DebugDiag.Analysis.exe.config
- C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\AnalysisRules\DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.dll.config