# How can I determine what's causing high memory usage in my Azure App Service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics

The app I run in Azure , a .net app is intermittently consuming a very high amount of memory usage.
If go into Diagnose and Solve problems , it seems the IIS process was consuming high memory which resulted in high CPU consumption, hence the application crashed
and then automatically recovered by restarting.
I have looked and downloaded logs but it doesnt actually outline what may be causing this high memory consumption.
Is it possible to determine and or catch the exception, more detailed errors that may have been causing this high memory usage ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Does this answer your question? [How to debug Azure Web App memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030776/how-to-debug-azure-web-app-memory-leaks)